# Tensorflow placeholder for one-hot encoded labels

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've one-hot encoded labels (11 classes ranging from 0 to 10):

```
# one-hot encode labels
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

labels = df.rating.values.reshape([-1, 1])
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
encoder.fit(labels)
labels = encoder.transform(labels)
```

And have the following placeholders:

```
# create the graph object
graph = tf.Graph()
# add nodes to the graph
with graph.as_default():
    inputs_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name='inputs')
    labels_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 1], name='labels')
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')
```

And I'm using `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy`:

```
with graph.as_default():
    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=outputs[:, -1], units=1)
    loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels_, logits=logits)        
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
```

TF throws: `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (500, 1, 11) for Tensor 'labels:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'`

I've tried everything and can't get it to work. What is the proper placeholder for one-hot encoded data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second dimension should be however many classes you have. One-hot encoding means that if you have let's say 10 classes, and you encode class 5, that will yield a vector [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] which is 10 long. So the code should be:

```
labels_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, ***number of classes***], name='labels')
```

Then again, [`tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy) takes a ***class label***, not one-hot encoding. So either you decode it with [`tf.argmax()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argmax) before feeding it to [`tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy) like so:

```
loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(
    labels = tf.argmax( labels_, axis = 1 ), logits = logits )
```

or the real question is why do you then use ont-hot encoding at all in the first place? You can just feed `df.rating.values.reshape([-1, 1])` to your graph as `labels_` and keep the 1 in the second dimension. The whole one-hot encoding block is unnecessary.

There are a few other issues in your code (not shown in original question) that affect this problem. First of all, you feed the network like this:

```
    feed = {inputs_: x,
            labels_: y[:, None],
            keep_prob: 1,
            initial_state: test_state}
```

In your effort to try to fix the `labels_` issue, you added the indexing `[:, None]`. The issue is that in Numpy the index `None` has a special meaning: it will insert a new dimension. So that's where the extra dimension in `( 500, 1, 1 )` comes from. Indexing `y` is unnecessary here, I've removed that. So the code should be:

```
    feed = {inputs_: x,
            labels_: y,
            keep_prob: 1,
            initial_state: test_state}
```

Then comes another issue, a very common mistake, in this line:

```
loss, state, _ = sess.run([loss, final_state, optimizer], feed_dict=feed)
```

you assign the value of `loss` to `loss`, therefore `loss` is now a ***number***, not the ***tensor*** it should be. So on the second iteration the code fails. I've changed it to

```
loss_val, state, _ = sess.run([loss, final_state, optimizer], feed_dict=feed)
```

but of course you need to propagate that change to the `print()` as well:

```
print("Epoch: {}/{}".format(e, epochs),
      "Iteration: {}".format(iteration),
      "Train loss: {:.3f}".format(loss_val))
```

Also, where you define your logits, you have to have 11 units, since you have 11 classes ( 0 - 10 ), and you need one probability for each class:

```
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=outputs[:, -1], units=11 )
```

With these changes the training runs, even seems to learn something:

> ('Epoch: 0/10', 'Iteration: 5', 'Train loss: 1.735')
>   ('Epoch: 0/10', 'Iteration: 10', 'Train loss: 2.092')
>   ('Epoch: 0/10', 'Iteration: 15', 'Train loss: 2.644')
>   ('Epoch: 0/10', 'Iteration: 20', 'Train loss: 1.596')
>   ('Epoch: 0/10', 'Iteration: 25', 'Train loss: 1.759')
>   Val acc: 0.012
>   ('Epoch: 0/10', 'Iteration: 30', 'Train loss: 1.581')
>   ('Epoch: 0/10', 'Iteration: 35', 'Train loss: 2.213')
>   ('Epoch: 0/10', 'Iteration: 40', 'Train loss: 2.176')
>   ('Epoch: 0/10', 'Iteration: 45', 'Train loss: 1.849')
>   ('Epoch: 0/10', 'Iteration: 50', 'Train loss: 2.474')
>   Val acc: 0.017

Comment: I've tried that before, but then it throws `Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 11 for 'sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_loss/remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [?,11].` at `loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels_, logits=logits)`

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I've tried that as well (not using one hot encoding)... but it throws `Cannot feed value of shape (500, 1, 1) for Tensor 'labels:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'`

And if I instead use `softmax_cross_entropy` with one-hot, throws `Received a label value of 10 which is outside the valid range of [0, 1).`

Comment: And if I make the placeholder `None, 1, 1`, throws `Rank mismatch: Rank of labels (received 3) should equal rank of logits minus 1 (received 2).`

Comment: You do have to have labels as shape `(None, 1)`. How do you get the extra dimension? For each image you have one label.

Comment: I just noticed `tf.argmax( labels_, axis = 1 )`, after adding that, throws `Fetch argument 0.0 has invalid type <class 'numpy.float32'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a float32 into a Tensor or Operation.)`

Comment: The extra dimension comes from one hot encoding... as it replaces integers with arrays of integers.

Comment: Yes, but then the dimension's size should not be 1. I don't understand what's going on. From your first block, use this: `labels = df.rating.values.reshape([-1, 1])` to feed into your network, with `labels_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 1], name='labels')` and `loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels_, logits=logits)`, that should work. If it doesn't, then post the whole code and I'll fix it for you.

Comment: I tried it again and still can't get it to work. I uploaded the code to https://github.com/seifip/predict-nps - thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Fixed it, added explanation to my answer. My github user is pszoldan, if you add write permission, I'm happy to push the changes to you repo too.

Comment: I just tried making the additional changes but still get `Received a label value of 10 which is outside the valid range of [0, 1)`. If you could push your changes to github, would be very kind of you! Added you as collaborator.

Comment: Pushed the changes to github

Comment: hmmm... I still get `Received a label value of 10 which is outside the valid range of [0, 1).` I wonder if it's something with my setup... I'm using Python 3.6.4 (via Anaconda), Jupyter 4.4.0, TensorFlow 1.7.0

Comment: oh I see... on CPU it's this error, on GPU it throws NaN... that's mentioned in tensorflow docs.

Comment: `Each entry in labels must be an index in [0, num_classes). Other values will raise an exception when this op is run on CPU, and return NaN for corresponding loss and gradient rows on GPU.`

Comment: Logit units changed to 11. Please retest. Pushed to repo as well. (Managed to keep commit to the relevant line this time :) )